# Same Javascript function not runs one another one it runs parallel

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dom-events

This is my code:

```
var bonusTiles = true
if (bonusTiles) {
  function myfunc() {
    alert("tet tet");
    removeMatches(bonusTiles, true);
    myfunc1(function test() {
      var bonusTiles = true
      if (bonusTiles) {
        removeMatches(bonusTiles, true);
      }
    });
  }
  myfunc();

  function myfunc1(callback) {
    alert("tet tet");
    callback();
  }
}
```

In the above code, I have called the `removeMatches` function in `myfunc` and `myfunc1`. In this the `removeMatches` functions in `myfunc` and `myfunc1` are running parallel.

I need to run `removemaches` in `myfunc` and after it finishes, then run `mufunc1`.

I used a `setTimeout` function. It's working but the `removemaches` function is 
varying over time.

Comment: and what is removematches?

Comment: removeMaches function removes the element in the DOM. but returns nothing

Comment: add all the function code you used here

Comment: how to run the removemaches function simultaneously without settimeout

Comment: JavaScript is single threaded. Save for very specific cases specifically implemented to be asynchronous (such as AJAX) the situation you describe can simply not happen. I presume there's something else here you haven't shared.

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag = removeMatches(bonusTiles, true);
if (flag) {
 myfunc1();
}

function removeMatches () {
 //write your main code here
 return true;
}
```

OR another way

```
if(removeMatches(bonusTiles, true)) {
    myfunc1(function test() {
      var bonusTiles = true
      if (bonusTiles) {
        removeMatches(bonusTiles, true);
      }
    });
}
```